# ATLAS BLAS Windows

Tags: windows, blas, atlas

I am trying to install ATLAS BLAS package.
The solution would be write on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

The problem is that I am running on Windows, so don't have the sudo neither apt-get command.
How could I install it ?

Comment: With conda install is neither possible... keep geting the error that ATLAS doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, I just stumbled on your question searching for something else.

First, the command that you want to use (`apt-get install`) mainly concerns Debian-based Linux operating system and not Windows.

Second, it would install base BLAS and LAPACK libraries that are not [ATLAS](https://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/).

I think that you have at least two possibilities:

- use [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) to install and run a Linux subsystem on your Windows machine, like a Ubuntu Linux distribution (more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) for the installation instruction), in which you will be able to use `apt-get install` command to install packages, and specifically `apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` for ATLAS, and any other software packages that you would need to run your computations.
- directly install ATLAS in Windows, following the instructions on their [website](https://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node54.html), based on the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) software.

Maybe, other alternatives exist.